# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Crashes After New Pushes

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance for a project. It pulls source code from GitHub. And initial setup is fine, the link works. But, after doing new pushes, the instance fails. It keeps saying no data is being sent back by the instance:
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ogMO.png)

Comment: you need a full log to figure out the issue.  go to the beanstalk console and retrieve the full log